# I'm having problems moving an programatically added UIIMAGEVIEW

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

So , i am having a problem moving some images with touchesBegan and touchesMoved here is my code for the p1 UIImageView

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];


    NSLog(@"incepe");

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (touch.view == self.p1) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

        self.p1.center = location;
        NSLog(@"nmk");
    }

}
```

and the way i add the pictures is this

```
-(void)img{
    if (!self.p1) {
        self.p1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14,20,70,50)];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.p1]; 
}
```

the touchesmoved event is not triggred when i press the p1 UIImageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting `p1.userInteractionEnabled = YES`

Answer (score 0):

Have a I look at this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pgr1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(image1Moved:)];
    [yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:pgr1];

}

-(void)image1Moved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pgr{
    NSLog(@"Came here");
     [yourImageView setCenter:[pgr locationInView:self.view]];
}
```

**P.S** yourImageView should have `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`